# How to set up Kinect Xbox 360 webcam in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, usb, webcam, xbox-360

I have been looking to set up my Kinect Xbox 360 webcams in Ubuntu 20.04 but without success. Also, I have followed these [instructions](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/920053-azure-kinect-dk/suggestions/40368301-support-for-ubuntu-20-04-lts) and [commented](https://github.com/microsoft/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/issues/1263).

Verify sensor library using `k4aviewer` shows No available devices.
[image]

when I run `./bin/Protonect`, I got:

```
Version: 0.2.0
Environment variables: LOGFILE=<protonect.log>
Usage: ./bin/Protonect [-gpu=<id>] [gl | cl | clkde | cuda | cudakde | cpu] [<device serial>]
        [-noviewer] [-norgb | -nodepth] [-help] [-version]
        [-frames <number of frames to process>]
To pause and unpause: pkill -USR1 Protonect
[Info] [Freenect2Impl] enumerating devices...
[Info] [Freenect2Impl] 9 usb devices connected
[Info] [Freenect2Impl] found 0 devices
no device connected!
```

Comment: I just wrote a fairly comprehensive answer, hope it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67427653/2199369

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try it and let you know.